# Unable to connect to PostgreSQL on Google Cloud Instance

Tags: postgresql, google-app-engine

I have postgreSQL runiing on my google cloud instance and i added firewall rule "tcp 5432" on Google cloud firewall but still i am unable to connect, even telnet is not working.

```
officetaskpy@instance-1:/etc/postgresql/9.5/main$ netstat -ntpl
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5910          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9020/Xvnc
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:44801           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16023/phantomjs
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53619           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      812/phantomjs
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Result of netstat command

[image]

Above is my firewall rule. Is there anything which i am missing here.